# How to obtain same routing logic for ApiControllers as regular Controllers in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: c#, controller, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I started out with a Controller that takes filter parameters like this:

```
public class CampaignsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult List(string searchstring, string pid, string country, string vertical, string traffictype)
    {
         var query = db.Campaigns;
         if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(country))
         {
              query = query.Where(c => c.CountryCode == country);
         }
         // and so on...      
         var viewModel = new CampaignListViewModel { Campaigns = query.ToList(); }
         return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

What I liked about this is that actions mapped to it even if some of the parameters are null.

Then I converted over to an Ajax style and found the ApiController to be convenient as a way to generate the JSON responses I needed.

However, I have found that *all* of the parameters need to present in the query string in order for the route to match up to the Action.

Here is the sample code for that:

```
    public class CampaignsApiController : ApiController
    {
        public IQueryable<CampaignViewModel> Get(string vertical, string traffictype, string search, string country, int? pid)
        {
            var campaigns = db.Campaigns.AsQueryable();
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(vertical))
            {
                var cr = db.Verticals.Where(v => v.Name == vertical).FirstOrDefault();
                if (cr != null)
                    campaigns = campaigns.Where(c => c.Vertical.Name == vertical);
            }
            // and so on...
            var query = campaigns.AsEnumerable()
                       .Select(c => new CampaignViewModel(c))
                       .AsQueryable();
            return query;
        }
   }
```

Is it possible to obtain the same behavior for the ApiController?

Alternately, could my design approach or the way I am using the ApiController be modified in a way to coalesce the ApiController default behavior to the result I am after?

Here's the [gist](https://gist.github.com/3784952) of the two classes for reference.

Comment: Can you show your routing code?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting in some default values for the parameters that might be missing, e.g.

```
public IQueryable<CampaignViewModel> Get(string vertical = null, string traffictype = null, string search = null, string country = null, int? pid = null) {

 ...

}
```

Comment: Did it work? There was a similar issue in the pre-release versions.

Comment: I got routed to a different fire but I'll get to test this later in the week - thanks!